# How to write data to a text file without overwriting the current data

Tags: c#, text, overwrite

I can't seem to figure out how to write data to a file without overwriting it. I know I can use File.appendtext but I am not sure how to plug that into my syntax. Here is my code:

```
TextWriter tsw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Hello.txt");

//Writing text to the file.
tsw.WriteLine("Hello");

//Close the file.
tsw.Close();
```

I want it to write Hello every time I run the program, not overwrite the previous text file. Thanks for reading this.

Comment: What is @ meaning here ? thanks

Comment: @user2420472 "[The `@` special character serves as a verbatim identifier.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/verbatim)"  In this case, it means the backslash will not be used as an escape character, but as a verbatim backslash.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Pass `true` [as the `append` parameter of the constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36b035cb.aspx):

```
TextWriter tsw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Hello.txt", true);
```

Answer (score 10):

Change your constructor to pass true as the second argument.

```
TextWriter tsw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Hello.txt", true);
```

Answer (score 5):

You have to open as `new StreamWriter(filename, true)` so that it appends to the file instead of overwriting.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a chunk of code that will write values to a log file. If the file doesn't exist, it creates it, otherwise it just appends to the existing file. You need to add "using System.IO;" at the top of your code, if it's not already there.

```
string strLogText = "Some details you want to log.";

// Create a writer and open the file:
StreamWriter log;

if (!File.Exists("logfile.txt"))
{
  log = new StreamWriter("logfile.txt");
}
else
{
  log = File.AppendText("logfile.txt");
}

// Write to the file:
log.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);
log.WriteLine(strLogText);
log.WriteLine();

// Close the stream:
log.Close();
```

Answer (score 3):

Best thing is

```
File.AppendAllText("c:\\file.txt","Your Text");
```

Answer (score 1):

Look into the File class.

You can create a streamwriter with

```
StreamWriter sw = File.Create(....)
```

You can open an existing file with

```
File.Open(...)
```

You can append text easily with

```
File.AppendAllText(...);
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all check if the filename already exists, If yes then create a file and close it at the same time then append your text using `AppendAllText`. For more info check the code below.

---

```
string FILE_NAME = "Log" + System.DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString() + "." + "txt"; 
string str_Path = HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath + ("Log") + "\\" +FILE_NAME;


 if (!File.Exists(str_Path))
 {
     File.Create(str_Path).Close();
    File.AppendAllText(str_Path, jsonStream + Environment.NewLine);

 }
 else if (File.Exists(str_Path))
 {

     File.AppendAllText(str_Path, jsonStream + Environment.NewLine);

 }
```

Comment: It seems previous one was perfect.

Answer (score 0):

```
using (StreamWriter writer = File.AppendText(LoggingPath))
{
    writer.WriteLine("Text");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**none of the above did not work I found the solution myself**

```
 using (StreamWriter wri = File.AppendText("clients.txt"))
        {
            wri.WriteLine(eponimia_txt.Text + "," + epaggelma_txt.Text + "," + doy_txt.Text + "," + dieuthini_txt.Text + ","
                + proorismos_txt.Text + "," + poly_txt.Text + "," + sxePara_txt.Text + "," + afm_txt.Text + ","
                + toposFortosis_txt.Text + ",");
        }
```